# jquery remote posting and retrieving but error message is not displaying

Tags: jquery

I'm facing this validation not posting the error message please kindly help to resolve this issue. In em element it automatically taking as `display: none`

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
    <label class="label-control bmd-label-static" style="font-family: CircularAirPro;color:#727272;font-size: 14px;">Email *</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_data" id="emailval">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
$("#regval").validate({
  rules: {
    email_data: {
      required: true,
      remote: {
        url: 'email_check.php',
        dataType: 'POST',
        data: {
          'email': function() {
            return $('#emailval').val();
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  messages: {
    email_data: {
      required: "email field required",
      remote: "Email already exist"
    }
  },
  errorElement: "em"
});
```

After validating it returns false but next to that it is displaying none in em but it has to display the error message. Like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pending valid" name="email" id="emailval" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="emailval-error">
```

It is not displaying the error message

Comment: <em id="emailval-error" class="error" style="display: none;"></em>like this iam  getting

Comment: process working fine but in false it has to display the error but it's not displaying

Comment: Check that the request is returning a response successfully in the console.

Comment: ya it's responding  it's return false

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: {
    url: 'email_check.php',
    **dataType: 'POST',**
    data: {
      'email': function() {
        return $('#emailval').val();
      }
    }
  }
```

instead of **dataType** need to replace **type**

```
  remote: {
    url: 'email_check.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'email': function() {
        return $('#emailval').val();
      }
    }
  }
```